# Python "SSL: UNSUPPORTED PROTOCOL" error when using urllib3 on a https site

Tags: python, ssl, https, urllib3

I'm using urllib3 to get the html content of a website via a socks proxy.
Unfortunately this does not work on any website. Running this on a few sites will give me an error.

```
import urllib3
from urllib3.contrib.socks import SOCKSProxyManager
proxy = SOCKSProxyManager('socks5://myProxyIP:8080')
r = proxy.request('GET', "https://urlofwebsite", preload_content=False)
```

> urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError:
>   SOCKSHTTPSConnectionPool(host='urlofwebsite', port=443): Max retries
>   exceeded with url: /index.php (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL:
>   UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL] unsupported protocol (_ssl.c:727)'),))

I assume this might be an issue with the SSL (or TLS) version the site is using but as I am not the owner of the server I have to edit my script to handle with this.

Is it possible to change the setting in urllib3 to accept this connection?

Thanks!